# Como calcular preço de item a partir de quantidade aleatória de itens vendidos?

Tags: java, random

Estou resolvendo um problema, e uma das partes dele é calcular o preço de um item baseado na quantidade aleatória deste mesmo item vendido. Por exemplo: 4 itens foram vendidos, então, o método deve calcular o preço de 4 itens vendidos. Esse número 4 foi gerado aleatoriamente.

Eu criei uma classe, que possui como variáveis os itens a serem vendidos, criei um método para cada item, para gerar um valor aleatório de cada item, e outros métodos, para gerar o preço dos itens baseado na quantidade de itens vendidos (gerados aleatoriamente). O problema é que a quantidade de itens gerados não está batendo com o preço dos itens vendidos.

Aqui está o método para gerar uma quantidade aleatória de hambúrgueres, por exemplo:

```
public class Mês {
private int hamb;

public double vendaHamb (){
    Random rand = new Random();
    hamb = rand.nextInt(5)+1;
    return hamb;
}

public double precoHamb (){
    double preco= vendaHamb()*78.00;

    return preco;
}
}
```

Já procurei bastante casos parecidos e não encontrei. Quando crio um objeto da classe, e tento calcular o número de hambúrgueres vendidos, e o preço deles, o valor dos hambúrgueres vendidos é gerado aleatoriamente, mas o preço deles também, o preço não corresponde com o valor de itens vendidos, como se não usasse o número que foi gerado mesmo. Agradeceria se pudessem me ajudar.

Comment: Tente alterar o tipo de retorno do método pra int.

Comment: acho que o que acontece é que ele gera um novo numero randon a cada chamada, ou seja, se voce chamar o vendaHamb ele retorna um numero, e caso logo em sequencia voce chame o precoHamb ele vai chama o vendaHamb e vai gera um novo numero randomico...

Comment: Eu também supus a mesma coisa. Por isso, gostaria de saber se alguém tem alguma idea de como usar o primeiro valor gerado randomicamente, porém de maneira fixa no segundo método. Já procurei muito sobre isso, mas não encontrei nada, então, talvez nem seja possível, mas como ainda estou aprendendo, não tenho certeza.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public double precoHamb (){
   double preco= vendaHamb()*78.00;

   return preco;
}
```

Tente alterar esse trecho do código para:

```
public double precoHamb (){
   double preco= hamb * 78.00;

   return preco;
}
```

Senão cada vez que você calcular o valor do hambúrguer vai gerar um novo número aleatório.